# How add Continuous Deployment from Git from a .Net project?

Tags: asp.net, git, azure

I see in Azure that I can add a Git Repository to Azure and it automatically do deployments from it.

I tested successfully with an old project that has only Classic ASP. I think its very cool with a JavaScript only site too. These type of projects are not compiled. Just upload the changed files to the server and we are ready.

But how to do it with a .Net project where I generate compiled files? I need to create another repository for the Production files? or a branch or how is the "best practice" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1-Host your code on github, and allow github to publish new version to your azure websites.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NGieL0tinw

2-Use local git repository and push to azure manually.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-git/

Comment: Thanks Thiago but I already did it in this way but with a Classic ASP project. My question is how I can do it with a .net Project? I can´t upload .cs files to Azure. I need to uplload only production files. Am I clear?

Comment: @Gabotron Same steps with .net project! 1-Init a local repo in your project directory. 2-Add all files. 3-Commit locally. 4-Push to Azure. PS: Just make sure you compile your project befor push to Azure.

Comment: @Gabotron what I said above, with screenshots: http://sireel-world.azurewebsites.net/sir-eel-visions/WATK-FS-Pt2

Comment: The more interesting part is "But when you deploy from a git repository, you upload source code to Azure, and Azure builds your application in the cloud using an open-source build engine called Kudu."
Thanks @Thiago-Custodio